# What changes in Android 8 makes it possible to update UI from non-ui thread

Tags: android, ui-thread

For the below sample code, it tries to update UI from a non-ui thread, this crashes on Android 4.x but works well on Android 8 (it surprised me!).

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView mTextView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

    mTextView = findViewById(R.id.test_text);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    test2();
}

private void test2() {
    mTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Util.log("AAA thread name " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

                    mTextView.setText("AAA");
                }
            }.start();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Want to know what changes on Android 8 makes this works.

EDIT: Stack trace for crash on Android 4:

`09-08 00:08:21.986 1811-1827/com.rainliu.androidexercise E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-107
                                                                           android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4607)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:835)
                                                                               at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15129)
                                                                               at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15129)
                                                                               at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15129)
                                                                               at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15129)
                                                                               at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15129)
                                                                               at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15129)
                                                                               at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:292)
                                                                               at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15129)
                                                                               at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:6303)
                                                                               at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3547)
                                                                               at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3405)
                                                                               at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3380)
                                                                               at com.rainliu.androidexercise.rxjava.RxJavaActivity$4$1.run(RxJavaActivity.java:320)`

Comment: It definitely shouldn't...

Comment: In your test is this a hit-or-miss scenario or it always works without an error?

Comment: add stack-trace & thread-names of the Android 4.x crash.

Comment: @TheWanderer, shouldn't what? Shouldn't work on Android 8 or shouldn't not work on Android 4? :)

Comment: @Enzokie, always work on my Android 8 emulator (the one built-in with Android Studio)

Comment: @MartinZeitler edited and added stack-trace

Comment: @LiuWenbin_NO. It shouldn't work on 8

Comment: @TheWanderer I think so too, so it really makes me surprising!

Comment: @LiuWenbin_NO. The framework has to explicitly call a method to check the calling thread for a View. Someone probably just forgot to call it when needed. Don't count on this behavior to work.

Comment: @TheWanderer I think you're right, don't count on this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

class [Thread](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html) has not changed since API level 1.

just tried, while `Thread.currentThread().getName()` either gives me thread `main` when using `.run()` or `Thread-2` when using `.start()`; while both do not appear to be background threads.

one can verify that with `Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper()` ...

or with `Looper.getMainLooper().getThread() == Thread.currentThread()`.

```
new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper()) {
            mTextView.setText(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        } else {
            Log.w(LOG_TAG, "not the main thread");
        }
    }
}.run();
```

just see [Processes and Threads](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads), which explains why this is working...

despite it will block the `main` thread for a second.

so why it crashes on Android 4.0 and what are the thread names there?

and I've just found a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FWwMA-sdOgk), which explains the difference.

Comment: ```if (Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper()) {
                            mTextView.setText("In Main looper: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                        } else {
                            mTextView.setText("Not in Main looper: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                        }``` On Android 8: The TextView shows: 'Not in Main looper: Thread-4'

Comment: Crash for the above code on Android 4.0: 09-08 00:08:21.986 1811-1827/com.rainliu.androidexercise E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-107
                                                                           android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Comment: @LiuWenbin_NO. the difference is, that later versions use the `main` `Thread`, while earlier versions create a separate  "worker" `Thread` instead. I have tested that with Android 8.0 on hardware... while `Thread-2` was no "worker" thread either.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand (I think `the later version` means Android 8), I started a new Thread and, it is not in the main looper, how should that work to update UI on a non-ui thread? (I tried to open the Process and Threads link and the video, unfortunately they are not available in my area...)

Comment: @LiuWenbin_NO. with later I mean `>= level 26`... while before you'd need to use a `Handler`, in order not to get the `CalledFromWrongThreadException`. see https://medium.com/@jagsaund/android-handler-internals-b5d49eba6977

Comment: @MartinZeitler OP is targeting 26 and running on 26, and is showing you that the new thread isn't running on main.

Comment: @TheWanderer I'm talking about what the device is telling me ...and as I've already stated, the difference `main` vs. `Thread-N` is just `.start()` vs. `.run()` ...of course `Thread-N` is not equal `main`, but nevertheless it updates the `View`, hence it is not being run in the background.

Comment: @MartinZeitler oh of course. I didn't notice you were using run() in your example. But OP is using start(), so I'm still not sure I understand your answer.

Comment: I checked `Processes and Threads`, but it seems not related with my question. My code doesn't mention Handler.